# Why won't my scripts load?

Tags: functions, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, scripts, wp-register-script

I am having trouble loading scripts in functions.php

I've done this before so I'm sure I'm overlooking something but as far as I can tell it is correct and I have tried copying and pasting from other answers. I am not getting any console errors. None of my scripts are loading in the source at all. Help is appreciated.

**functions.php**

```
/*SCRIPTS*/

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );

function theme_js(){

    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap_min_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_min_js' );
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn’t working? Is the script tag not appearing at all on the page? Are you using a child theme?

Comment: The script doesn't load at all. I'm not sure what a child theme is, I code my themes from scratch so I don't believe so.

Comment: When you say it doesn't load, what exactly do you mean? The script isn't doing what you want? There's an error in the console? The `<script>` tag isn't in the source at all?

Comment: In my question I included I am not receiving console errors, I will edit it to specify the script tag is not in the source at all.

Comment: Does your theme have `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in it?

Comment: It did not so I added them, cleared my cache and the header and the footer is loading now (I had it hard coded before as a test but I've corrected it thanks to your suggestion) but the scripts still do not appear in the source.

Comment: I found the issue thanks to your suggestions. I didn't have <?php wp_footer(); ?> at the end of my footer.php file. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` call at the end of the footer.php file.